# Android calculate the grid corner positions in android Google map

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, android-studio

I want to a gird of 4 rows and 3 columns on Googmap. I want to show marker on topLeft and bottom right corner of each Rectangle made by grid.

Here is the code i am using

```
public void getVisibleRegionGrids(final VisibleRegion region)
{
    int columns = 3;
    int rows    = 4;

    double mainTopLat  = region.latLngBounds.southwest.latitude;  // (c, d)
    double mainTopLng  = region.latLngBounds.northeast.longitude;

    double mainBottomLat = region.latLngBounds.northeast.latitude;
    double mainBottomLng = region.latLngBounds.southwest.longitude;

    double horizontalDiff = Math.abs (( mainBottomLat - mainTopLat ) / columns);  // 1
    double verticalDiff   = Math.abs (( mainBottomLng - mainTopLng ) / rows);  // 1

    double topLat  = mainTopLat;  // (c, d)
    double topLng  = mainTopLng;

    //double bottomLat = mainTopLat + horizontalDiff;
    //double bottomLng = mainTopLng + verticalDiff;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < columns ; x++)
        {
            double currentTopLat = (topLat + (i * verticalDiff)) + (x * horizontalDiff);
            double currentTopLng = (topLng + (i * verticalDiff)) + (x * horizontalDiff);

            double currentBottomLat = currentTopLat + horizontalDiff;
            double currentBottomLng = currentTopLng + verticalDiff;
            try
            {
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                        .draggable(false)
                        .position(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(currentTopLat), Double.valueOf(currentTopLng))
                        );
                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                        .draggable(false)
                        .position(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(currentBottomLat), Double.valueOf(currentBottomLng))
                );
                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            }catch (Exception e)
            {}
        }
    }
}
```

i CAN't get its logic to work. I have calculated topLeft and bottom right points. Starting from topLeft, i want to proceed. What can i do

***Update***

Thanks to the help, i have managed to make it work

```
public void getVisibleRegionGrids(final VisibleRegion region)
{
    int columns = 3;
    int rows    = 4;

    double mainTopLat  = region.latLngBounds.northeast.latitude;  // (c, d)
    double mainMaxLng  = region.latLngBounds.northeast.longitude;

    double mainBottomLat = region.latLngBounds.southwest.latitude;
    double mainMinLng = region.latLngBounds.southwest.longitude;

    double horizontalDiff = Math.abs ((mainMaxLng - mainMinLng ) / columns);  // 1
    double verticalDiff   = Math.abs ((mainTopLat - mainBottomLat) / rows);  // 1

    double topLat = mainTopLat;  // (c, d)
    double topLng = mainMinLng;
    int position = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < columns ; x++)
        {
            double currentTopLat  = (topLat - (i * verticalDiff));
            double currentLeftLng = (topLng + (x * horizontalDiff));

            if(position == i)
            {
                currentTopLat  = (topLat - (i * verticalDiff));
                currentLeftLng = (topLng + (x * horizontalDiff));
            }

            position = -1;

            if(x == columns)
                position = i + 1;

            try
            {
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                        .draggable(false)
                        .position(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(currentTopLat), Double.valueOf(currentLeftLng)));
                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                double currentBottomLat = currentTopLat - verticalDiff;
                double currentRightLng = currentLeftLng + horizontalDiff;
                markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                        .draggable(false)
                        .position(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(currentBottomLat), Double.valueOf(currentRightLng)));
                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            }catch (Exception e)
            {}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to have a few errors about coordinates.
Southwest is the lower left point and northeast is the topright one.
So

- mainTopLat is the northeast.latitude
- mainTopLng is the northeast.longitude -> Should be called mainMaxLng
- mainBottomLat is the southwest.latitude
- mainBottomLng is the southwest.longitude -> Should be called mainMinLng

I'm modifying the code inline so it could contain errors, but it should work for your case. Don't draw the lowerright marker except for last row and last column since it would draw a duplicate marker!

```
public void getVisibleRegionGrids(final VisibleRegion region)
{
    int columns = 3;
    int rows    = 4;

    double mainTopLat  = region.latLngBounds.northeast.latitude;  // (c, d)
    double mainMaxLng  = region.latLngBounds.northeast.longitude;

    double mainBottomLat = region.latLngBounds.southwest.latitude;
    double mainMinLng = region.latLngBounds.southwest.longitude;

    double horizontalDiff = Math.abs ((mainMaxLng - mainMinLng ) / columns);  // 1
    double verticalDiff   = Math.abs (( mainTopLat - mainBottomLat) / rows);  // 1

    double topLat  = mainTopLat;  // (c, d)
    double rightLng  = mainMaxLng;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < columns ; x++)
        {
            double currentTopLat = (topLat - (i * verticalDiff));
            double currentLeftLng = (topLng + (x * horizontalDiff));

            try
            {
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                        .draggable(false)
                        .position(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(currentTopLat), Double.valueOf(currentLeftLng)));
                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                if ((i==(rows-1))|| (x==columns-1){//add the lowerright marker only on the last line or column, avoid duplicated markers
                double currentBottomLat = currentTopLat - verticalDiff;
                double currentRightLng = currentLeftLng + horizontalDiff;
                markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                                .draggable(false)
                                .position(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(currentBottomLat), Double.valueOf(currentBottomLng)));
                    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }
            }catch (Exception e)
            {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @N Latitude is horizontal right? so should be considering minLat and max lat and topLng and bottomLng no? so horizontal and vertical diff should be changed

Comment: nope, Latitude is vertical and goes from -90 to 90, Longitude is horizontal and goes from -180 to 180.
The idea for you is to start from top left corner (topLat, minLng) and move in the grid (the double cycle scans moving right (columns) and when reached right side, goes to next line.
Rows are for decreasing latitude (you start from top), columns are for increasing Longitude(you start from minLng).
I've edited the code since there was  an error in  double currentLeftLng = (topLng + (x * horizontalDiff));

Comment: @N ok thanks for ur help . I have managed to make it work. I have done a number of modifications in your code. Now i have 12 different bounding boxes. Thanks again.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar you made modifications but that have no sense honestly:
If (position == i ) does exactly the same of the above lines, so it can be removed, (x==columns) will never be true because the condition in the loop is (x<columns) and it can be removed.
the rest is the same except that you draw the bottom right point always, this means you draw the marker two times. Anyway i'm happy you solved!

Comment: yes, but its not about adding marker, its about getting points. i need to get points not markers in association with its top point